# ユニバーサル Windows アプリの実行時にプラットフォームがWindowsなのかWindows Phoneなのかを判別するには？

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

※ そのものズバリな API ではないので、情報を共有します。

Windows 8.1 と Windows Phone 8.1 に対応したユニバーサル Windows アプリを開発する際に、現在利用されているプラットフォームを実行時に判別してロジックを分けたいと思います。
MSDNを見ても、それっぽいAPIが見当たりません。実現方法はありますか？

Answer (score 4):

Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation クラスを使います。次のコードで、実行中のプラットフォームが WindowsPhone であるか、そうでない(Windows)なのかがわかります。

C# で書いていますが、C++, Visual Basic, JavaScript からも同じ API を利用できます。

```
    bool DetectIfRunningOnWindowsPhone()
    {
        var info = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
        return (info.OperatingSystem.Equals("WindowsPhone")) ? true : false;
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx　も併せてご覧ください。

Answer (score 1):

簡易的な方法としては、EasClientDeviceInformationの他にも、次のような手段があります。

- Appクラスが入っているアセンブリの名前をリフレクションで取ってくる (作った人には区別が付くはず!)
- Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUriプロパティ（＝アプリが掲載されているストアのWebページのURI）で判別する

＠IT:「[WinRT／Metro TIPS：WindowsとPhoneでロジックを切り分けるには？［ユニバーサルWindowsアプリ開発］](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1405/22/news126.html)」

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx#CrossPlatform

WindowsとWindows Phoneそれぞれのプロジェクトにおいて、
条件付きコンパイルシンボルとして定義されている値を利用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
public bool IsPhone = false;

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        IsPhone = true;
#endif
```

APIも何も使わずなのでちょっとアレな感じもしますかね…